# How to remove an Open Graph Aggregation?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I added the `Video` type to our Facebook Open Graph application so we could post actions to our users' timelines. However, Facebook added twelve useless (for us) aggregations in addition to `Videos` and `Top Videos`, including `TV Shows`, `Episodes`, `Directors`, etc. How can I remove these from our application?

Not only does it clutter up our panel, but I'm reading in other questions that having aggregations without valid action/object previews causes problems with posting actions. And in fact, posting only works for the application creator--not developers or testers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had a similar experience.

When you select an object type proposed by Facebook (field auto completes when you type your object), Facebook creates a full list of pre made aggregations that are, in fact, overkill.

I could not find how to delete these pre-made aggregations, unless i actually deleted the linked object. Creating a new custom object type enabled me to create custom aggregations, which all have a blue cross on the right to delete them. This cross did not show on pre made aggregations.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up deleting the video object as we're not ready for it yet. I'll make sure to create it from scratch next time.